# Check if string starts with a set of keys and return the best matched key

Tags: java

Can someone fix the logic for finding the correct matching key.

```
public class Test {
    public String eventName(String fileName, List<String> validEvents) {
        System.out.println(validEvents);

        return validEvents.stream().filter(fileName::startsWith).findFirst().orElse(null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String eventNames ="scs_pre_stg_org,scs_pre_stg_orgmapping";

        String event = new Test().eventName("scs_pre_stg_orgmapping123", Arrays.asList(eventNames.split(",")));
        System.out.println(event); // scs_pre_stg_org :(
    }
}
```

This should be scs_pre_stg_orgmapping instead.

Comment: You need to not return the first but the longest match: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/123883/90168

Comment: Sort `eventNames` in descending order of string length in advance. Or use [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)

Comment: @luk2302 brilliant. Unless the question is closed, I could accept your answer if you post it as one.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the best-matched key by finding the `max` length string that matches the criteria of `startsWith`.

```
public String eventName(String fileName, List<String> validEvents) {
    return validEvents
               .stream()
               .filter(fileName::startsWith)
               .peek(System.out::println)
               .max(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length))
               .orElse(null);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After filtering, sort by length and grab the longest.

```java
public String eventName(String fileName, List<String> validEvents) {
    System.out.println(validEvents);

    return validEvents
            .stream()
            .filter(fileName::startsWith)
            .max(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length)) // get longest
            .orElse(null);
}
```

Comment: amazing :) simple solution that didn't cross my mind.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply sort the filtered strings in reverse order which will put the longest one first.

```
public String eventName(String fileName, List<String> validEvents) {
    System.out.println(validEvents);
    return validEvents.stream()
                      .filter(fileName::startsWith)
                      .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
                      .findFirst()
                      .orElse(null);
}
```